# Shows Error forbidden 403 when scraping table from https://www.mykhel.com/football/indian-super-league-team-stats-l750/

Tags: pandas, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Need help to understand how to scrape data from the link, below are my unsuccessful codes on google colab.
pd.read_html was working last year , but now shows "No tables found"

```
from six.moves import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests import get

url = """https://www.mykhel.com/football/indian-super-league-team-stats-l750/"""

url_contents = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(url_contents, "html")
div = soup.find_all("a")

content = pd.DataFrame(div)
content
```

```
html5="https://www.mykhel.com/football/indian-super-league-team-stats-l750/"

from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

site = html5

wd = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',options=options)
wd.get(site)
html = wd.page_source
df = pd.read_html(html)
df
```

```
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')


test_URL = 'https://www.mykhel.com/football/indian-super-league-team-stats-l750/'

def get_data(link):
    hdr = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.107 Mobile Safari/537.36'}

    req = requests.get(link,headers=hdr)
    content = req.content
  
    return content

data = get_data(test_URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
Mumplayer = soup.find_all("div",class_= "os-fifastatslist-table")
```

I'm expecting a df like below [image: pd.read_html was working last year but i`m not sure what changed]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is working for me. If you want to scrape other tables, check the tables variable containing a list of data frames.

**CODE**

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

URL = "https://www.mykhel.com/football/indian-super-league-team-stats-l750/"
header = {'Accept-Language': "en-US,en;q=0.9",
          'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 "
                        "(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
          }

resp = requests.get(url=URL, headers=header).text

tables = pd.read_html(resp)
overview_table = tables[0]

print(overview_table)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
                Team  Group Name  Matches  Wins  Draws  Losses  Points
0          Hyderabad         NaN        8     5      1       2      16
1             Odisha         NaN        7     5      0       2      15
2        Mumbai City         NaN        8     5      3       0      18
3                Goa         NaN        7     4      0       3      12
4    Kerala Blasters         NaN        7     4      0       3      12
5    ATK Mohun Bagan         NaN        7     4      1       2      13
6      Chennaiyin FC         NaN        7     3      1       3      10
7          Bengaluru         NaN        7     2      1       4       7
8     SC East Bengal         NaN        7     2      0       5       6
9      Jamshedpur FC         NaN        6     1      1       4       4
10  NorthEast United         NaN        7     0      0       7       0
```